# Any alternative to array datatype in SQL Server

Tags: sql, arrays, sql-server

PostgreSQL allows columns of a table to be defined as variable-length multidimensional arrays. Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE sal_emp 
(
    name            text,
    pay_by_quarter  integer[],
    schedule        text[][]
);
```

Some INSERT statements are as below

```
INSERT INTO sal_emp
VALUES ('Bill', '{10000, 10000, 10000, 10000}',
        '{{"meeting", "lunch"}, {"training", "presentation"}}');

INSERT INTO sal_emp
VALUES ('Carol', '{20000, 25000, 25000, 25000}',
        '{{"breakfast", "consulting"}, {"meeting", "lunch"}}');

SELECT * FROM sal_emp;
```

Output:

```
 name  |      pay_by_quarter       |                 schedule
-------+---------------------------+-------------------------------------------
 Bill  | {10000,10000,10000,10000} | {{meeting,lunch},{training,presentation}}
 Carol | {20000,25000,25000,25000} | {{breakfast,consulting},{meeting,lunch}}
(2 rows)
```

How can we achieve the same thing in SQL Server or any alternative to it?

Comment: There is no equivalent alternative in MS SQL. Only JSON https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921897.aspx in latest versions.

Comment: @IvanStarostin ...and XML (since SQL Server 2005) :-)

Comment: Muahmmad, Even if this might be supported, I would consider this as bad design. Such *depending lists* should live in `1:n`-related side tables... This concept has a *lazy smell* :-)

Comment: @Shnugo: It's not necessarily a bad design  (and it gets mis-used way too often in Postgres), if a single attribute of an entity **is** an array by nature then an array is a good choice. But in this case a one-to-many relationship would be a **much** better choice - even in Postgres

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, what is *an array by nature* that wouldn't be better solved with a side table? I don't know how this is solved under the hood, but I would not be surprised, if this is done with hidden side tables. If this is true, there wouldn't even be a performance argument...

Comment: I guess the real question is what kind of operations you are going to perform over these columns? If you are just storing them, using `NVARCHAR(MAX)` is fined (for example after the data is read from the table it can be rendered as `array` or `object` by the SS language you are using).

Comment: @Shnugo In Postgres this is **not** done via a "side table". It's single, compressable variable length data structure. Any attribute where you always read and write the entire array (for further processing in your applications) but never need to access individual elements from within SQL is a possible candidate for this (but again: the shown example is **not** a valid example for a good choice. I completely agree that the information shown should **not** be stored in array - not even in Postgres)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sounds a bit like *hidden XML or JSON* :-)

Comment: @Shnugo: you might be interested in this: http://www.databasesoup.com/2015/01/tag-all-things.html (see the size difference of the solutions in part 2) and this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219503/is-it-bad-design-to-use-arrays-within-a-database

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you, very interesting...

Comment: A table; each array element is a row. You are probably visualizing an array horizontally but it's pretty much the same when you visualize it vertically. I gave a lenghty answer on a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40542875/243373), it might be of value to you.

Comment: After reading the SQL Server documentation, 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx
I didn't find any alternative to it. Thank you all for supports.........!

Comment: Recommended reading for anyone thinking about arrays in SQL Server http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html. The link might say 2005 but it covers everything up until SQL Server 2016 (JSON)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is NO alternative to array datatype in SQL Server.